# Android app icon for different build version

Tags: android, icons

I'm trying to add launcher icon for my android application with adaptive icon features. The problem I'm facing that the icon works perfectly with android Oreo but it show android default android icon for pre Oreo devices.
How to set launcher icon according to different android versions?

Manifest code for icon :

```
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:roundIcon="@drawable/ic_logo"
```

ic_launcher.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<adaptive-icon xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <background android:drawable="@mipmap/ic_background"/>
    <foreground android:drawable="@mipmap/ic_foreground"/>
</adaptive-icon>
```

Comment: post your manifest XML.

Comment: have you added round icon?

Comment: Old question. At first read Official guideline

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya I followed the guideline and adaptive icon is working but not able to set icon for pre-oreo devices

Answer (score -1):

You can create adaptive icons in Android Studio like this

> Right Click on app > New --> Image Asset

And this 
[image]

You can choose your image, foreground layer and background layer and all